# Method not being able to be called from another class

Tags: java, class, methods

Currently I'm refactoring some old code, it was 16k lines of 1 object that did everything in the application. I inherited it and my goal is to make it better. For some reason when I'm pulling out a method making it into it's own class, the first class wont allow me to call the second method.

(Giant object)
Saveapp

```
BuildXMLFarmEndorsement buildFarmXML = new BuildXMLFarmEndorsement();
    buildFarmXML.buildXMLFarmEndorsements( multi, i);
```

for what ever reason my IDE will not recognize the code above. Here is the code of the new class

new class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BuildXMLFarmEndorsement  implements java.io.Serializable {
    public void buildXMLFarmEndorsements(MultiApp multi, int i) throws Exception{do some stuff}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in `try`-`catch`? It throws an Exception, maybe that has to be handled... What IDE do you use?

Comment: Check if those methods and fields are `public` and/or package-private.

Comment: Can be a package related issue as well.

Comment: Is it just the IDE or can you compile the code?

Comment: Which IDE do you use and what does it tell you? There should be some compiler error message.

Comment: Just tried it myself in eclipse, no problem when handling the `Exception` at method call...

Comment: Sorry I saw all of you are asking the IDE, I'm using eclipse, I have Sonar Lint on and all I'm getting is it is telling me to remove it as if it doesn't exist. I have the new class in the same package, and all ports are public.

Answer (score 0):

Check the packages and the visibility. And your imports.

Comment: everything is public and it is in the same package... I'm scratching my head over here.

Comment: can you upload it to github or bitbucket?

Answer (score 0):

I feel pretty silly, I was just calling the class outside of a method.